# Issues with absolute encoder ‎BRT38-SOM-1024-RT1. Values are instable

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, hardware

I am using an absolute encoder‎ (BRT38-SOM-1024-RT1) to read the position of a turntable that get moved by a stepper motor.

When I read the data, it seems instable - even if I do not move the table.

Example:
277.03125
97.03125
277.03125
97.03125
277.03125
277.03125
277.03125

Here is the code I am using:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

PIN_CLK  = 21
PIN_CS   = 16
PIN_DATA = 20

LOW   = GPIO.LOW
HIGH  = GPIO.HIGH

class Encoder:

    def __init__(self, clk_period=0.000001, wait_time_read=1):#0.0):
        self._clk_wait = clk_period / 2
        self._clk_init_wait = wait_time_read
        GPIO.setup(PIN_CLK, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(PIN_CS, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(PIN_DATA, GPIO.IN)
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        GPIO.output(PIN_CLK, HIGH)
        GPIO.output(PIN_CS, HIGH)

    def read(self):
        # start a new measurement
        data = []
        GPIO.output(PIN_CS, LOW)
        time.sleep(self._clk_init_wait)
        if GPIO.input(PIN_DATA) == 0:
            print("Failed to set SSI read mode")
            return None
        GPIO.output(PIN_CLK, LOW)
        time.sleep(self._clk_wait)
        for i in range(10):
            GPIO.output(PIN_CLK, HIGH)
            time.sleep(self._clk_wait)
            data.append(GPIO.input(PIN_DATA))
            if i < 9:
                GPIO.output(PIN_CLK, LOW)
                time.sleep(self._clk_wait)
        self.reset()
        return self.convert_to_int(data)

    def convert_to_int(self, binary_array: list) -> float:
        res = 0.0
        for i in range(len(binary_array)):
            res += binary_array[i] * 2**i
        return res / 1024 * 360.0

enc = Encoder()
for i in range(50):
    print(enc.read())
    time.sleep(1.0)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

I was trying to run the Encoder wit 3V3 and now with 5V (via a level shifter between D0 pin and the PI) but this also brings no improvement.